# How to pass a method from one class to another in ruby

Tags: ruby

Please help, the below code is what I have so far

Question:

Given the existing Employee class.

Define a class School (at the bottom of this file) which has a method `train`.
This train method should take in an employee as an argument, and upskill them.

```rb
class Employee

  def initialize
    @skill_level = 1
  end

  def upskill
    @skill_level += 1
  end

end

class School

  def train(employee)

  end

end
```

Comment: I don't see any inheritance here (apart from the implicit inheritance from `Object`).

Comment: You need to edit the title so that it does not refer to inheritance. Not doing so may attract downvotes, but it needs to be done regardless.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Knowing how to send a message to an object – e.g. `employee.upskill` – is very fundamental. You should probably learn how this works before implementing classes and method. See the docs for [Calling Methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html) or read a Ruby beginners tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just need to call the method on the `employee` argument.

```
class School
  def train(employee)
    employee.upskill
  end
end
```

Though, as a school *has* employees, it's likely the employee will be an instance variable when you see this kind of thing in real applications.